# Split a string (file name) using index position

Tags: c#, split, lastindexof

I need to separate the file name into an array of two strings.

The file name looks like this: `IMG-20190604-WA0005.jpg`

An array that I want:

[0] = "IMG-20190604-WA0005"

[1] = "jpg"

I got index position using `LasIndexOf('.')`

Comment: [`string.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @derpirscher Can you give an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use string methods but the available methods in [`System.IO.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0):

```
string file = "IMG-20190604-WA0005.jpg";
string filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
```

If you don't want the . at the beginning, remove it:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.');
```